# Approximating/estimating values

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, approximation, network

I am working on a study of epidemic models for heterogeneous networks.

I have the following expression

$$1-e^z (1-z) + z^2(\gamma + \ln z + z + O(z^2))$$

where $\gamma$ is the Euler-Mascheroni constant. This is an expansion of the total epidemic prevalence $R_\infty$ of a network model with power-law degree distribution as presented in this [article](https://arxiv.org/pdf/cond-mat/0107267.pdf). Here is a snippet:

> $\quad$ The equation for $\,R_\infty,\,$ with the connectivity distribution $(34)$ is
> $$ R_\infty = 1-2m^2\int_m^\infty k^{-3}e^{-\lambda k\phi_\infty}dx =
> 1 - 2z^2\int_{z}^\infty x^{-3}e^{-x}dx, \tag{35} $$
> where we have defined the new variable $\,z=\lambda m\phi.\,$
> Performing the integral, we obtain
> $$ R_\infty = 1-e^{-z}(1-z) - z^2\Gamma(0,z), \tag{36} $$
> where $\,\Gamma(a,z)\,$ is the incomplete Gamma function [37]. For small
> values of $\,z\,$, the function $\,\Gamma(0,z)\,$ can be expanded in the
> expression [37]
> $$ \Gamma(0,z) \approx -(\gamma_E + \ln z) + z + \mathcal{O}(z^2), \tag{37} $$
> where $\,\gamma_E\,$ is the Euler's constant. By inserting this expression into
> the expression for $\,R_\infty,\,$ we obtain for small values of $\,\phi_\infty\,$
> $$ R_\infty \approx 2z \equiv \lambda\langle k\rangle \phi_\infty. \tag{38} $$

How will this expression approximately equal $2z$? Is there a way where I could find possible upper bounds to terms in this expression such that I could approximate it to $2z$? I would appreciate any help or any direction I could start with for this problem. Thank you so much for your time.

---

snippet image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ulv3X.png

Comment: What is the context? Where did this expression come from? Why do you think it is approximately $2z$?

Comment: @Somos it's from an expansion of $R_\infty$ from a network model with power-law distribution. Yes, the literature says it is approximately $2z$ and I'm trying to figure out why. Here is the link for reference: [link](https://arxiv.org/pdf/cond-mat/0107267.pdf)

Comment: Please include the context in the question itself. Did you try to plot the value of the expression for a small range of positive real numbers? Since we don't know what $R_\infty$ is I don't know how we can help.

Comment: @Somos apologies. I have edited the question to include the reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your helpful snippet it is more clear what is going on. From Wikipedia
[Incomplete gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incomplete_gamma_function)
for the upper incomplete gamma function we have

> $$\Gamma(0,z) = \underset{s\to 0}\lim \big(\Gamma(s) -
>   \frac1s - (\gamma(s,z) - \frac1s)\big) = -\gamma - \ln(z) -
>   \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(-z)^k}{k(k!)} $$
> is the limiting function to the upper incomplete gamma function as
> $\,s\to 0,\,$ also known as the exponential integral $\,E_1(z).^{[5]}$

Multiply both sides of equation $(37)$ by $\,-z^2\,$ to get

$$ -z^2 \Gamma(0,z) = z^2(\gamma + \ln(z)) - z^3 + \mathcal{O}(z^4). $$

Now expand in power series the expression

$$ 1-e^{-z}(1-z) = 1 - (1 - z + z^2/2 + \mathcal{O}(z^3))(1-z) = \\
1 -(1-2z+3z^2/2 +\mathcal{O}(z^3)) = 2z-3z^2/2 +\mathcal{O}(z^3). $$

Adding these two equations gives

$$ 1-e^{-z}(1-z) -z^2 \Gamma(0,z) = 2z + z^2(\gamma -3/2 + \ln(z)) 
+\mathcal{O}(z^3). $$

Comment: is there any intuition behind the last two terms approximating $0$ for the entire expression to approximate to $2z$? I tried graphing and it does not appear so.

Comment: @user1178472 I don't know what you graphed and why you think "it does not appears so". My final result is only a truncation. There are an infinite number of terms. Intuition is individual so I can't comment on that.